# Does magit support interactive git hook?

Tags: magit, hooks, git

My git hook would prompt for answer yes/no when do the push. How could I get the prompt and enter my input when using `Magit`?

Answer (score 1):

This will likely just work. If not, then you might have to customize `magit-process-yes-or-no-prompt-regexp`.